# PHP Array duplicate data count

Tags: php

I have title and language data in PHP Array. I need to display repeated title count. Please check below array format.

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [title] => My_title1 [language] => English ) 
  [1] => Array ( [title] => My_title1 [language] => English ) 
  [2] => Array ( [title] => My_title2 [language] => Japanese ) 
)
```

I need to display data in following format.

```
Title      Language   Count
My_title1  English    2
My_title2  Japanese   1
```

I tried following code

```
$count = array_count_values(array_map(
function($item) {
    return $item['title'];
}, $testArray));
print_r($count);
```

but I got only title counts.

```
Array ( [My_title1] => 2 [My_title2] => 1  )
```

How do I display like following format?

```
Title      Language   Count
My_title1  English    2
My_title2  Japanese   1
```

Comment: are the values `English`, `Japanese` etc. supposed to be strings? or did you `Define()` them as constants?

Comment: English and Japanese are not constants. Languages are strings. It will be vary based on Titles. Ex: My_Title3 may be Chinese language and My_Title4 may be English Language etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it for example this way:

```
<?php

$testArray = array ( 
  0 => Array ( 'title' => 'My_title1', 'language' => 'English' ), 
  1 => Array ( 'title' => 'My_title1', 'language' => 'English' ), 
  2 => Array ( 'title' => 'My_title2', 'language' => 'Japanese' ), 
); 

$count = array_count_values(array_map(
function($item) {
    return $item['title'].'#'.$item['language'];
}, $testArray));

$outArray = array();

foreach ($count as $k => $v) {
    $k = explode('#', $k);
    $record['Title'] = $k[0];
    $record['Language'] = $k[1];
    $record['Count'] = $v;

    $outArray[] = $record;
}

var_dump($outArray);
```

Of course you need to use character that will not be used inside title and language, probably `#` is quite good enough

Answer (score 1):

Try this code code which i created just for this assignment

```
<?php
$array = array(
       0 => array ( 'title' => 'My_title1', 'language' => 'English'), 
       1 => array ( 'title' => 'My_title1', 'language' => 'English'), 
       2 => array ( 'title' => 'My_title2', 'language' => 'Japanese')

    );
    $final = array();

    foreach($array as $key =>$value)
    {
        $flag = 0;
        foreach($final as $key1 =>$value1)
        {

            if($array[$key]['title'] == $final[$key1]['title'])
            {
                $final[$key1]['count']++;
                $flag = 1;
            }

        }
        if($flag == 0)
        {
            $push = array('title' => $array[$key]['title'],'language' => $array[$key]['language'],'count' =>1);
            array_push($final,$push);
        }   
    }
echo "<pre>";print_r($final);
```